# Removing small contours and noises from a thresholded image in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, image-segmentation

Are there any methods or functions to remove small contours given an already thresholded image through OpenCV in Python? My aim is only letting the rectangles and soon separate these overlapped ones:

[image]

[image]

Comment: One method is to apply a morphology open on the thresholded image before getting and filling contours. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn what are appropriate questions for this forum and how to ask them and to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem.

Comment: Hi @fmw42, thanks for the tip. In fact, I have already applied this procedure (opening + erosion) here, but there are only some regions that I am trying to keep (in this case only the rectangles) to draw at the original image, and the unwanted regions still continue. I have already tried to find other posts where it is explained but the other ones are in C++ or Matlab what didn't help me. This help that I am asking is because I have a college work to do applying them and I am very stuck on them. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the blobs you are trying to remove are small compared to the blobs you want to keep, one way is to draw bounding boxes around the blobs and discard unwanted blobs using the area of the bounding box.

```
    cnts = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
    rect_areas = []
    for c in cnts:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        rect_areas.append(w * h)
    avg_area = mean(rect_areas)
    for c in cnts:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cnt_area = w * h
        if cnt_area < 0.5 * avg_area:
            img[y:y + h, x:x + w] = 0
```

Here I am removing blobs with area less than half of the average areas. You can set this value experimentally for the value you want.

Comment: I was struggling here before this answer for another approach to discover and I found another one this very morning, I was evaluating smaller or larger contourArea values and the ones that I drew had to fit at this condition, check it out what you think:

Answer (score 1):

One another approach that I have reached this morning complementing your one for the same problem and to contribute as well, evaluating by the condition of the contour area of the rectangle:

```
_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
image_copy = image.copy()
for c in contours:
#Defining a condition to draw the contours, a number larger than/smaller than or between ranges
x = 5000.0
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > x:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.drawContours(image_copy, [c], 0, (0,255,0), 17)
```

I believe that must have other ones and better than this one that I have done to avoid to print determined contours also that I am looking for, and some short ones that I am trying to solve